# How to set LLMConfiguration Model to Claude 3?

Tags: authentication, llm, llmfunction, serviceconnect

I have an API key, but I'm not sure how to set the default for new chat-enabled notebooks to Claude 3? Is this supported, if not in the UI, what about programatically?

[image]

Also, I'd like to put my Gemini keys in as well, any workarounds for that?

Comment: What does Claude 3 say to do?  (I'm being completely serious)

Comment: I use claude 2.1, does MMA repopulate the options? I don't see that one listed...

Comment: It looks like this is an open issue on the LLM Chatbook Github repository https://github.com/WolframResearch/Chatbook/issues/614 

Behind the scenes, it appears that Anthropic has migrated from a "Competions" API (supported above) to a new "Messages" API (which is not supported yet by MMA) https://docs.anthropic.com/claude/reference/migrating-from-text-completions-to-messages

Answer (score 7):

As of Mathematica 14.0 on 08 March 2024, neither the built-in `LLMSynthesize` nor the [Anthropic Service Connection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Anthropic.html) are compatible with the new Messages API (they use the [older Text Completion API](https://docs.anthropic.com/claude/docs/upgrading-from-the-text-completions-api))

```
LLMSynthesize["What version are you?",
 LLMEvaluator -> <|"Model" -> {"Anthropic", "claude-3-sonnet-20240229"}|>]

(* ServiceExecute::apierr: The service returned the following error message: "claude-3-sonnet-20240229" is not supported on this API. Please use the Messages API instead.. *)
```

```
ServiceExecute["Anthropic", "Chat",
 {"Messages" -> {<|"Role" -> "User",  "Content" -> "What version are you?"|>},
  "Model" -> "claude-3-sonnet-20240229"}]

(* ServiceExecute::apierr: The service returned the following error message: "claude-3-sonnet-20240229" is not supported on this API. Please use the Messages API instead.. *)
```

However, you can still make the requests through manual API calls if you follow [Anthropic's Messages API documentation](https://docs.anthropic.com/claude/reference/messages_post):

```
req = HTTPRequest[
  URL["https://api.anthropic.com/v1/messages"],
  <|"Headers" ->
    <|"x-api-key" -> apiKey, (*define your own API key somewhere else*)
     "anthropic-version" -> "2023-06-01",
     "content-type" -> "application/json"|>,
   "Body" -> ExportString[#, "JSON"] &@
    <|"model" -> "claude-3-sonnet-20240229",
     "max_tokens" -> 1024,
     "messages" -> {<|"role" -> "user","content" -> "What version are you?"|>}|>
   |>]

result = URLRead[req];

Query["content", All, "text"] @ ImportString[#, "RawJSON"]& @ result["Body"]

(* {"I'm afraid I don't have a specific version number. I'm an AI \
assistant created by Anthropic to be helpful, harmless, and honest."} *)
```

Comment: Some extended examples over at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3142280